# Disable Firestore cache for a single query

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

problem: the stream view shows old data for a brief moment.
showing old data is useful on other streams, so I don't want to disable it for the entire project, but on one specific screen, it confuses the user.

I'm using Firebase Firestore for a flutter app, I want to disable It’s offline service only on one screen and one stream, not for the entire project, I know how to disable persistence on initialization, but I need to disable it only for a single query.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you describe the actual problem you have, that you think bypassing the cache will fix?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've added some information about the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't listen for a stream in a way that bypasses the local cache. But you can detect in your callback whether a document was instantiated from the cache (and may be stale) by checking the [`DocumentSnapshot.metadata.isFromCache` property](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/SnapshotMetadata/isFromCache.html). If the `isFromCache` is false, the snapshot is guaranteed to be up to date with the server.